# How to update state with setState before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'll preface this by stating that I'm a complete beginner at React.js

I've created an example of a project I'm working on where I call an API in componentDidMount() and get an array of objects back, setting it in state. Here's what it looks like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        thing: []
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    // Fake API
    const apiCall = () => ({
      data: "test"
    })

    // Fake call
    const data = apiCall()

    this.setState({
        thing: [
            ...this.state.thing,
            data
        ]
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{ this.state.thing[0].data }</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I'm aware that setState isn't guaranteed to update when it's used according to the documentation. I also found "forceUpdate()," and the docs recommends using it as little as possible. Nevertheless, I attempted to use it, but to no avail.

I'm able to console.log the new state during the componentDidMount() run and in the render's h1 element, but I'm unable to actually show it in the render since it's rendering an empty state array at first.

**My question is**:
Is there a way to force my state to update before the render is run by my program so that I can see it, and if not, how would I be able to see my new state reflected in the JSX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is called after the initial render and hence, at the time of initial render `this.state.thing[0]` is undefined and hence it would cause an error, you need to perform a conditional check before using `this.state.thing[0].status`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        thing: [
            {
                status: "running",
                test: "testing"
            }
        ]
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.thing.length > 0? <h1 className="mt-5 mb-5">{ this.state.thing[0].status }</h1>: null
}
            <button className="mt-5" onClick={ this.handleUpdate } value="not running">
                Click to change
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes there is a way to setState before the initial render and that is with `componentWillMount`. It is the first lifecycle method to be called in React. The lifecycle method `componentDidMount` is called after the initial render.

However, looking at your code I'm not sure what the use case is for using `componentWillMount`.  Instead of setting state in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`, just set a default state in your constructor function. Then you have the state you want on the initial render and can update it on events accordingly, i.e. your button.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        thing: [
            {
                status: "running",
                test: "testing"
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel! The reason I would be using componentDidMount to set the state rather than initializing it beforehand is because I'm calling an API and setting the state based off of that call. Without the API, the state would be an empty array, which would render nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the other [React lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

It sounds like you want `componentWillUpdate` or `shouldComponentUpdate` methods..